How to apply stippling to contourf plots in Python?
I want to add stippling to Xarray DataArray data to indicate significance. The data is 2D climate data on a lat lon grid. I want to give a True/False mask to plot over mapped variable data. I am trying to use contourf for this purpose, but I am open to other methods if they are more suitable.
I have tried using contourf hatching to stipple the significant regions, but the stipple dots cover all the plot area. When I add the contourf with the mask and hatches, the 0 and 1 values are also plotted in solid colour, obscuring the variable data I want to visualise.
I have found MATLAB stipple documentation and a similar question for R "adding stippling to image contour plot".
This question may be similar. As suggested by the answer for that question, I tried providing levels but that did not solve my issue here.
Below is an illustrative example of my problem.
The desired output would be the left contourf plot with stippling dots only where the mask is True.
The right plot shows my attempt. You can see that the stippling hatches are over all the plot, regardless of the mask and the mask values are obscuring the values of the DataArray.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr

def f(x, y):
    return np.sin(x) ** 10 + np.cos(10 + y * x) * np.cos(x)

x = np.linspace(0, 5, 51)
y = np.linspace(0, 5, 41)

X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z = f(X, Y)

da = xr.DataArray(Z, coords = {"lon":x, "lat":y}, dims=["lat", "lon"])

fig =plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))
ax1 = plt.subplot(121)
ax2 = plt.subplot(122)

ax1.contourf(da.lon, da.lat, da)

mask = da>0.5
ax2.contourf(da.lon, da.lat, da)
ax2.contourf(da.lon, da.lat, mask, hatches=["."])



If you look at the second example in the Contourf Hatching page you linked, it uses None for the range without hatching.  So I would try hatches=[None, "."].

Hi RuthC, thanks, that has made some progress! Using hatches=[None, "."] shows stippling only in the True area. Now, how can I show the underneath at the same time?

This question is similar to: overly patches which represent the significants points over contour map. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Ok, I just tried your suggestion. Unfortunately, using contour removes the fill and also the stippling. All that is left is an outline between True and False

Oops, I responded to your comment before I saw you edit and change your comment RuthC.

Thanks for linking that other question. I don't understand how levels helps in my case. I tried to understand the other question and apply the answer for my question, but I still cannot solve the problem. If you can understand how it applies, can you please use it to answer the question I have asked?

I have edited the question to include how the answer to the similar question does not resolve this issue.

Try this ax2.contourf(da.lon, da.lat, mask, 1, hatches=['', '.'], alpha=0)

@HMH1013 Thank you! That works well. Your answer adds a blank hatch hatches=['','.'] and makes the True/False colouring transparent alpha=0 so that the original data is visible. I also amended your suggestion and ax2.contourf(da.lon, da.lat, mask, hatches=['', '.'], alpha=0) also works identically (as far as I can tell). Please add your comment as an answer so I can accept it. I believe this answer will be helpful for others, it's something I've wanted to be able to do for a long time.

I confirm that adding a blank hatch, as suggested by @HMH1013, works well:
ax2.contourf(da.lon, da.lat, mask, hatches=['', '.'], alpha=0)
That behaviour only started to happen in a recent version of Matplotlib for me.
